# Dependencies for special make target .DEFAULT not firing

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu-make

I am writing a makefile for a medium sized C++ project, and am employing the special `.DEFAULT` target to allow the storage of system-specific paths and settings in system-specific sub-makefiles.  For reasons I don't understand, dependencies don't seem to work with `.DEFAULT` as they do with other targets.  For example, consider the makefile:

```
.DEFAULT: zed
    @echo $@
bar: zed
    @echo bar
zed:
    @echo zed
```

If I call `make bar`, I see

```
zed
bar
```

But if I type `make foo`, I see only

```
foo
```

Why is `.DEFAULT` behaving differently?  How do I achieve dependencies for unnamed targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.DEFAULT` isn't like a regular target. It has very specific behaviour.

From the [`GNU Make Manual`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets):

> .DEFAULT
>
> The recipe specified for .DEFAULT is used for any target for which no rules are found (either explicit rules or implicit rules). See Last Resort. If a .DEFAULT recipe is specified, every file mentioned as a prerequisite, but not as a target in a rule, will have that recipe executed on its behalf. See Implicit Rule Search Algorithm.

<strike>So the documentation fairly clearly indicates that prerequisites of the `.DEFAULT` target do not operate like normal prerequisites.</strike> I now believe I misread the documentation above and it is not clear what the prerequisites of the `.DEFAULT` rule do/how they are handled. So I looked in the source to find out.

And, after some source diving, it turns out that the implementation of `.DEFAULT` in GNU make is a bit interesting.

If you look at [line 1859](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=4.1#n1859) of main.c you can see where make manually creates the (internal) file entry for the `.DEFAULT` rule.

```
default_file = enter_file (strcache_add (".DEFAULT"));
```

This is *before* any makefiles are read/etc. (that happens on [line 1895](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/main.c?id=4.1#n1895)).

If you then look starting at [Line 502](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/remake.c?id=4.1#n502) of remake.c you can see make trying to come up with rules for files for which it doesn't already have any.

```
/* If file was specified as a target with no commands,
   come up with some default commands.  */

if (!file->phony && file->cmds == 0 && !file->tried_implicit)
  {
    if (try_implicit_rule (file, depth))
      DBF (DB_IMPLICIT, _("Found an implicit rule for '%s'.\n"));
    else
      DBF (DB_IMPLICIT, _("No implicit rule found for '%s'.\n"));
    file->tried_implicit = 1;
  }
if (file->cmds == 0 && !file->is_target
    && default_file != 0 && default_file->cmds != 0)
  {
    DBF (DB_IMPLICIT, _("Using default recipe for '%s'.\n"));
    file->cmds = default_file->cmds;
  }
```

The first bit isn't relevant to us here but I left it in to show the type of operation make is performing at this point.

That second bit is the important bit. If the current file has no commands and is not a target and there is a default file entry and that entry has commands then copy the default file's commands as the current file's commands.

There are a couple of other references to `default_file` in the source but none of them are relevant to the current topic.

Notice what else we haven't seen? Any special handling of `.DEFAULT` as it actually gets read from a makefile. That first pre-creation just seeds the internal cache and allows make to refer to the `default_file` entry by variable easily. It doesn't fill in the commands or prerequisites or anything.

When make actually gets to reading the `.DEFAULT` rule from the file during normal operation it will find the pre-created file entry and fill that in with details. But what that means (and a quick test confirmed this) is that the `.DEFAULT` rule is read and handled like any other.

So, and this is the end of our tale, you can actually run `make .DEFAULT` and it will work (and run the listed prerequisites) because the special case processing of `.DEFAULT` is limited to populating the commands of any non-target targets and nothing else (apparently).

Oh, and while I used the make 4.1 source for the examples there the code hasn't changed since at least 3.81 and while I didn't check I assume it hasn't changed post-4.1 either.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still not sure I understand how this describes handling of prerequisites of `.DEFAULT`.  As I read it, the documentation states `.DEFAULT` will match prerequisites of other rules for which no rules exist, but does not discuss prerequisites of `.DEFAULT` itself.

Comment: @user1590768 I was going to say that the "If a .DEFAULT recipe" sentence was talking about prerequisites of the `.DEFUALT.` target itself but I'm not sure that's actually true. So you are right, it doesn't clearly indicate how those work. Which means my comment about it being clear was incorrect. We may need to wait and hope that @MadScientist chimes in here (or for me to go source diving).

Comment: The behavior certainly looks like it ignores any explicit targets and instead does what it says in the documentation.

Comment: @tripleee It clearly seems to ignore explicit prerequisites but I can't actually see the documentation discussing that behaviour (at least not in the section I excerpted). There may be another section that discusses this or it may be undocumented. I'll probably go poke around the source later and see if I can find anything.

Comment: Thanks for your very complete answer!  I find it a little surprising that prerequisites are not copied from `.DEFAULT`, but you have made it perfectly clear this is expected behavior.  I'll be sure to upvote after earning 15 reputation.

Comment: @user1590768 It is the current and historical behavior that's for sure. I just realized I should go look and see if the behaviour of `.DEFAULT` is specified and it turns out that apparently `POSIX` says that ".DEFAULT If the makefile uses this special target, the application shall ensure that it is specified with commands, but without prerequisites. The commands shall be used by make if there are no other rules available to build a target."